# Dividing line in a matrix

Tags: math-mode, equations, matrices

How can I Tex this equation?

[image: figure]

I try to have exactly the same result but for the moment I only succeeded in having intersecting lines... Thanks!

Comment: Please show us the code you already have. Why make people type it for you and make the same 'errors' like you when trying to find some solution?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could use `\midrule`, a macro provided the `booktabs` package, inside an `array` environment. This setup will assure that the horizontal line will not intersect the vertical lines.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\[
M = 
\left( \begin{array}{c|c}
   A & B \\
   \midrule
   C & D \\
\end{array}\right)
\]
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum* to address a follow-up question: If `A` has to be replaced with a `3x4` matrix, say, I suggest you do so by using a `matrix` environment (provided by the `amsmath` package) for the matrix, as is done in the following example.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}  % for '\midrule' macro
\usepackage{amsmath}   % for 'matrix' environment
\begin{document}
\[
M = 
\left( \begin{array}{@{}c|c@{}}
   \begin{matrix}
      a & b & c & d \\
      e & f & g & h \\
      i & j & k & l 
   \end{matrix} 
      & B \\
   \cmidrule[0.4pt]{1-2}
   C & D \\
\end{array} \right)
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: How to replace A, for instance, by a real matrix, a 3×4 matrix, say. @Mico

Comment: @HusseinEid - I've posted an addendum to address your question.

Comment: booktabs recommends that you never use vertical lines in a table.  This suggests to me that while this may work at the moment, it may not work in a future version of the package.

Comment: @Teepeemm - The `booktabs` package has been very stable since 2000. The updates since then have either just fixed bugs or added compatibility with packages such as `longtable` and `colortbl`. Do you have specific information regarding future changes to the `booktabs` package?

Comment: No information at all.  But its author's denunciation of vertical lines makes me suspect that he hasn't even tried to test putting them into a table, and I wouldn't be surprised if vertical lines caused some sort of error down the road, either because of a slight change in booktabs, or because of a slightly different table that someone else is creating.

Comment: @Teepeemm - I wholeheartedly agree with the view that vertical lines in tables should be avoided at (nearly...) all cost. Several years ago, I stopped using vertical lines in the tables of my own working papers, and as a result the tables look (and read!) much better. :-) The use case for the matrix is somewhat different, though: For some reason, the OP wants the horizontal line to be continuous and the vertical lines to be discontinuous. Achieving such a look is quite easy with `booktabs` and its `\midrule` and `\cmidrule` macros, but a lot more involved if one were to use other approaches.

Answer (score 14):

A way of achieving this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
  \[
    M = \left(
    \begin{array}{c|c}
      A & B\\
      \hline
      C & D
    \end{array}
    \right)
  \]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I believe the OP does *not* want the horizontal and vertical lines to intersect.

Comment: @Mico I wonder, it is not very clear. Better that I had a go with this answer, it will be an occasion to clarify this.

Answer (score 3):

Intercolumn space needs some adjustment but ...

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
  \[
    M = \left(\begin{array}{c@{}c@{}c}
      A & | & B\\
      \hline
      C & | & D
    \end{array}\right)
  \]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
$$ \left( \frac{A|B}{C|D} \right) $$
```

[image]

Comment: No, no , no, don't use $$....$$. It's 'outdated' and pure TeX. `\[...\]` is the better way. And it looks more like a block matrix than a pure fraction

Comment: See the posting [Why is \[ … \] preferable to $$ … $$?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503/5001) for a discussion of why it's unwise to use `$$` in a LaTeX document.