# Matrices with Annotations

Tags: math-mode, matrices

[image: Two matrices with additional info marked on them]

Do you have any suggestion how to make such formula? Or maybe I need to draw them somehow?

Big thanks for any hints!

Comment: Tikzmark.  See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/525421/highlighting-rows-columns-diagonals-in-matrix for example.

Comment: possible duplicate --https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/534149/197451

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest using `nicematrix`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{nicematrix, tikz}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{pNiceArray}{rrrrr}[first-row]
\downarrow && \downarrow && \downarrow\\
1 & 3 & 3 & 2 & 1\\
2 & 6 & 9 & 5 & 2\\
-1 & -3 & 3 & 0 & 1\\
3 & 9 & 6 & 5 & 2
\end{pNiceArray}
\sim
\begin{pNiceArray}{rrrrr}[first-row]
\downarrow && \downarrow && \downarrow\\
1 & 3 & 3 & 2 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 3 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 2\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\CodeAfter
\tikz \draw (2-|1)--(2-|3)--(3-|3)--(3-|5)--(4-|5)--(4-|6);
\end{pNiceArray}
\]
 
\end{document}
```

If you want to tighten up the spacing in the first matrix, you can change the first line to `\begin{pNiceArray}{@{\,}r@{\;}rrrr}[first-row]`

[image]

Comment: Thank you! <3
Will upvote once I have 15 reputation points.