# How to programmatically insert an \hline between each line of an array

Tags: matrices, arrays

I'm trying to create an environment for matrices that are divided in four sections, such as the following:

[image]

Ideally, I'd like to make it so that it can be used like the following:

```
M = 
\left(
\begin{croosmatrix}
   \begin{matrix}
      a & b & c & d \\
      e & f & g & h \\
      i & j & k & l 
   \end{matrix} 
      & B \\
   C & D \\
\end{crossmatrix}
\right)
```

I already know how to achieve such result manually, as decribed in [Dividing line in a matrix](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/240859/dividing-line-in-a-matrix). Something like the following:

```
M = 
\left(
\begin{array}{c|c}
   \begin{matrix}
      a & b & c & d \\
      e & f & g & h \\
      i & j & k & l 
   \end{matrix} 
      & B \\
   \hline
   C & D \\
\end{array}
\right)
```

My question is, how could I make it an environment? In other words, is there a way to programmatically place an `\hile` between each like on an array? Is it possible to create an environment for such a thing?

Comment: I'd recommend just to switch to `nicematrix`, which supports blocks and lines and much more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `nicematrix` which constructs the matrix while creating Tikz nodes. You can use these nodes to draw what you want with Tikz.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}

\NewDocumentEnvironment {crossmatrix} { }
  { \begin{pNiceArray}{cc}[margin] }
  {
    \CodeAfter
    \tikz \draw (2-|1) -- (2-|3) (1-|2) -- ([yshift=1pt]2-|2) ++ (0,-2pt) -- (3-|2) ;
    \end{pNiceArray}
  }

\begin{document}
$M = 
\begin{crossmatrix}
   \begin{matrix}
      a & b & c & d \\
      e & f & g & h \\
      i & j & k & l 
   \end{matrix}
      & B \\
   C & D 
\end{crossmatrix}$
\end{document}
```

[image: Result of the above code]

Comment: +1. I would put everything on one `\draw` command `\draw (row-2-|col-1) -- (row-2-|col-3) 
  (row-1-|col-2) -- ([yshift=1pt]row-2-|col-2) ++ (0,-2pt)
       -- (row-3-|col-2) ;`, mostly because, while you are not doing this, your code may be mistaken to nest `tikzpicture`s.

Comment: @ Schrödinger's cat: You're right. I have modified my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You want to insert to the item of the outer table (`\halign`) the nested table (`\haling`). It is not problem if the nested `\halign` is realized as a macro which reads its parameter in `{...}`. Then such parameter can include tabs `&` and `\cr` used for its inner nested `\halign`. But if you want to use a macro with separated parameter and not in `{...}` then the tabs `&` and `\cr` in such parameter are interpreted *during reading of the parameter* as tabs for outer `\halign`.

The nested `\begin{matrix}..&..&.\end{matrix}` reads its parameter terminated by `\end{matrix}` (no in `{...}`), so tabs `&` used here are interpreted by the outer `\halign`. Of course, you can hide these tabs by `{\begin{mattrix}..&..&.\end{matrix}}` but the LaTeX logic of tagging tables and using nested LaTeX environments is lost.

The following example shows the problem in native TeX language:

```
\def\a#1{\vbox{\halign{##&##\cr#1\cr}}}

\halign{X#Y&Z#W\cr    ..\a{b&c}..& d\cr}
```

Works, because the `b&c` is read inside `{}`, so the `&` here is not interpreted by the outer `\halign`.

```
\def\a[#1]{\vbox{\halign{##&##\cr#1\cr}}}

\halign{X#Y&Z#W\cr    ..\a[b&c]..& d\cr}
```

Doesn't work because when `b&` is read into the parameter then TeX interprets `&` as the tab for outer `\halign` and the reading of the parameter continues by `Y` followed by `\endtemplate` which is prohibited read it to a parameter.

```
\def\a[#1]{\vbox{\halign{##&##\cr#1\cr}}}

\halign{X#Y&Z#W\cr    ..{\a[b&c]}..& d\cr}
```

Works.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the syntax. Here I propose to specify the parts as arguments to the environment.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newenvironment{crossmatrix}[3]
 {
  \left(
  \def\crossmatrixfinal{&#1\\\hline#2&#3}
  \begin{array}{@{}c|c@{}}
  \begin{matrix}
 }
 {
  \end{matrix}
  \crossmatrixfinal
  \end{array}
  \right)
 }

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{crossmatrix}{B}{C}{D}
  a & b & c & d \\
  e & f & g & h \\
  i & j & k & l 
\end{crossmatrix}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]